# Когда в командной строке lunux при вводе "echo *" будет вывод "*", т.е. просто звездочка

Tags: linux, bash, unix, командная-строка

Вопрос из лабораторной работы
Суть уже описана. В каких **двух** случаях при вводе "echo *" будет вывод "*"? Один из случаев - если мы напишем эту команду, находясь в директории с единственным файлом, имеющим название "*". А какой второй?

Comment: очевидно, что в пустом каталоге.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin или в каталоге, в котором имена всех файлов начинаются на точку

Comment: @andreymal, и не установлена опция dotglob. p.s. к каталогам и сокетам тоже относится.

Comment: И не установлена опция `nullglob` =)

Comment: а ещё если определить функцию типа: `echo() { printf "*\n";}`... или отключить встроенную echo (`enable -n echo`) и добавить скрипт со своей реализацией в `PATH`...

Comment: Почему только **двух**? В юниксах всё можно сделать тысячью способами.